# Parse media file and get full text description in RSS Feed for ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, rss-reader

I have a requirement where I need to parse RSS Feed media files (videos and images) and then display them as below:

[image]

my code which I have used to display info other then media (I searched on web but did not find anything useful)

```
  string RssFeedUrl = "RSSFeedURL HERE";

        List<Feed> feeds = new List<Feed>();
        try
        {
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
            xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
            var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                         select new
                         {
                             title = x.Element("title").Value,
                             link = x.Element("link").Value,
                             pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                             description = x.Element("description").Value
                         });
            if (items != null)
            {
                foreach (var i in items)
                {
                    Feed f = new Feed
                    {
                        Title = i.title,
                        Link = i.link,
                        PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                        Description = i.description
                    };

                    feeds.Add(f);
                }
            }

            return View(feeds);
```

Here are the issue that I am facing:

1. How to make sure that RSS Feed have full text description and all
   media files?
2. How to parse media files
3. How to display media file to
   desired place in working

condition.

I hope my requirement is clear .. please share suggestions.

Comment: this is not relevant but the condition `items != null` is always true. and you don't need it.you can change your query and create a list of `Feeds` directly: use `select new Feed { .. }` instead of `select new` and add a `ToList` end of your query.

Comment: #Selman22 thanks for reply .. the code I have shared is working fine but I dont have knowledge how to use this to parse media file .. my main motive to get media element from rss feed and display it to desired position ..